# Dynamic TapGestureRecognizer on StackLayout in XamarinForms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the code below, which I'm basically looping a list and using the properties of that list as values:

```
SLTData.g_RecentLoans.ForEach(x => {
    colorCode = loanHistoryViewModel.GetStatusColor(x.ActivityListID);
    principal = utilities.FormatCurrency(x.PAMT);
    formattedDate = loanHistoryViewModel.ConvertDate(x.DateRequested);

    stackRecentList.Children.Add(
             new Frame {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                Margin = new Thickness(30, 20, 30, 0),
                Padding = new Thickness(10),
                CornerRadius = 5,
                HasShadow = true,
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Spacing = 0,
                    Children = {
                        // Content here
                        // The 'x' variables are used inside this StackLayout
                    }
                }
            }
        );
});
```

The thing is, I want to add a TapGestureRecognizer in each iteration of the StackLayout in the loop. I have tried adding `.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer)` at the closing bracket of the StackLayout but it says `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Xamarin.Forms.View'`

What I basically want to do is to add an argument to the function that handles the tap, and that argument is the keyword that gets passed to the API.

Comment: That is because you must be applying it to the Add method, check the brackets and apply it to your View!!!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a TapGestureRecognizer in each iteration of the StackLayout in the loop.

Maybe you have some problems when add tapGestureRecognizer for StackLayout, I provide some code that you can take a look:

```
  private  void loadtap()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            Frame f = new Frame()
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                Margin = new Thickness(30, 20, 30, 0),
                Padding = new Thickness(10),
                CornerRadius = 5,
                HasShadow = true,

            };

            StackLayout stack = new StackLayout()
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Spacing = 0,
                Children = { new Label(){Text="this is test"}

                }
            };

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
              DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been click tap", "OK");
            };

            stack.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
            f.Content = stack;

            stacklist.Children.Add(f);
        }
    }
```